# How to show tooltip with with more than one data bound in DataGrid's row?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tooltip

I have a DataGrid in WPF application showing one column. I want to have a tootip that shows all data from each row. It's something like this (this works):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ScreenName" Binding="{Binding Name}" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

If I change the Binding to another property (like Value="{Binding Age}") also works, shows the age in tooltip. In my Setter, how do I bind all the data to show in a single tooltip? Name, Age, City, Birthday, MoreData...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the converter

```
   <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}" />

    public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //Create your string here from properties
            return tooltiptext;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use MultiBinding:

```
   <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{0} {1} {2}">
            <Binding Age />
            <Binding Name />                                        
            <Binding City />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
```

Comment: where does `<Setter.Values>` go specifically?